# appendChild is slow

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

**Javascript**:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var div = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.appendChild(div);
div.className += " red"; // this should happened after appendChild()
```

**CSS:**

```
div{color:blue; transition: all 2s;}
div.red{color:red;}
```

**What I want:**

Assigning a "red" `class` to `div`, should make nice color animation. I want to `append` a `div`, then assign a `class`, so it will animate.

**What i got instead**:

Div is already appended red, with no animation going on.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: javascript is not multithread. Nothing happened with DOM, while js code executed.

Comment: What does the title have to do with your question?

Comment: I think it will work if you change it to `setTimeout(function(){div.className += " red"}, 0);`. This gives the browser a chance to render the blue div first, and then it will probably animate the transition. Currently the whole script is run before the page is rendered, so from the renderer's point of view, the classname is there from the start. May differ per browser. In Edge this may work correctly (untested).

Comment: As a sidenote, you can use `div.classList.add('red')`. The classList collection is a bit easier to work with, especially if you want to check for classes or remove them. Browser support is pretty good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using css animations instead?

I would suggest something like this:

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yurude/edit?html,css,js,output)

// css

```
div {
  animation: toRed 2s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   width: 200px; height: 200px;
}

@keyframes toRed {
    0%      { background-color: blue; }
    100%    { background-color: red; }
}
```

// javascript

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var div = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.appendChild(div);
```

This way you don't necessarily need to keep track of an extra class.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is not multithread.
Nothing happened with DOM, while js code executed.

You should delay execution to event-loop for animation:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  div.className += " red";
}, 0/*or other amount of ms*/);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you make DOM changes in Javascript, they're all rendered at once when it returns to the main event loop. Intermediate values aren't seen.

You can use `setTimeout()` to add the `red` class after the code returns.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    div.className += " red";
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a timeout to delay the addition of the `.red` class.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    div.className += " red";
}, 0);
```